# LINQ query where column contains a specific number >= specific value you want to query

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table named SubcodeTable and I want to query in SubsidiaryCode where first 3characters is >= to 21Y

```
Query in table where a column contains >= '21Y'
 SubcodeTable:
Column1         Column2
SubsidiaryCode  Desc
18Y-001         AAA
19Y-001         AAA
20Y-001         AAA
21Y-001         CCC
22Y-003         EEE
23Y-001         FF
So output should display:
Column1         Column2
SubsidiaryCode  Desc
21Y-001         CCC
22Y-003         EEE
23Y-001         FF
```

By the way first 3 characters of SubsidiaryCode represent year like 21Y=2021.

I manage to create a SQL query, so how do to it in **LINQ query** ?

SQL query:

```
SELECT LEN (Whh_SubsidiaryCode) [StringLength],LEFT(Whh_SubsidiaryCode,2)[FirsttwoCharInSubCode]
,Whd_WHNo [RR NUMBER], Whh_SubsidiaryCode [SubsidiaryCode], Whd_WHSeqNo [SEQ], Whd_WHSplitSeqNo [SPLIT SEQ] ,Whd_WHIssuedQty [QTY],Saw_StockName [ITEM NAME],Saw_StockSpecs1 [ASSET DESCRIPTION]
FROM E_WHDetailEntry
JOIN E_WHHeaderEntry ON Whd_WHNo=Whh_WHNo
JOIN E_StockAndWorkMaster ON Whd_StockCode=Saw_StockCode
WHERE Whd_StockType='FS2'
AND Whh_SubsidiaryCode LIKE '%Y%' AND LEFT(Whh_SubsidiaryCode,2) >= '21'
ORDER BY Whh_SubsidiaryCode
```

So this is my LINQ query, I tried to use `y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Substring(0,2) >'20'` but it says Too many characters in car literal & operator > cannot be applied to operands of type string and char.

```
private List<string> GetBudgetCodes()
{   
    using (var ctx = LinqExtensions.GetDataContext<NXpert.FixedAsset.DataAccess.FixedAssetDataContext>("AccountingDB"))
    {
        var list = (from x in ctx.DataContext.E_WHDetailEntries
                    join y in ctx.DataContext.E_WHHeaderEntries
                    on x.Whd_WHNo equals y.Whh_WHNo
                    where x.Whd_StockType == "FS2"
                     && y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Contains("y")
                     && y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Substring(0,2) >= '21'
                    select new { y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode }
                   ).DistinctBy(y => y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode).OrderBy(y => y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode).ToList();

        var budgetcode = list.Select(y => y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Trim()).ToList();
        return budgetcode;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your Linq code so that we can help you

Comment: I added my LINQ querry.

Comment: How about  if you cast to integer fist like `Convert.ToInt32(y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Substring(0,2)) > 21`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in exception

```
> cannot be applied to operands of type string and char.
```

You need to parse `Whh_SubsidiaryCode` first to be able to compare values.

So this

```
&& y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Substring(0,2) >= '21'
```

should be like this:

```
&& Convert.ToInt32(y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Substring(0,2)) > 21
```

Comment: Okay this is working fine, but how can I select all Subcode and returns "22Y-001" format then convert it back to string?

Comment: And also it returns an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'LP to data type int'"

Answer (score 0):

I finally gotten a solution in SQL.
by using **LEN** then get the length then using **LEFT** to get the first 2 char.

Then create a where clause for the condition:
LEFT(Whh_SubsidiaryCode,2) >= '20'

```
SELECT LEN (Whh_SubsidiaryCode) [StringLength],LEFT(Whh_SubsidiaryCode,2)[FirsttwoCharInSubCode]
,Whd_WHNo [RR NUMBER], Whh_SubsidiaryCode [SubsidiaryCode], Whd_WHSeqNo [SEQ], Whd_WHSplitSeqNo [SPLIT SEQ] ,Whd_WHIssuedQty [QTY],Saw_StockName [ITEM NAME],Saw_StockSpecs1 [ASSET DESCRIPTION]
FROM E_WHDetailEntry
JOIN E_WHHeaderEntry ON Whd_WHNo=Whh_WHNo
JOIN E_StockAndWorkMaster ON Whd_StockCode=Saw_StockCode
WHERE Whd_StockType='FS2'
AND Whh_SubsidiaryCode LIKE '%Y%' AND LEFT(Whh_SubsidiaryCode,2) >= '20'
ORDER BY Whh_SubsidiaryCode
```

**Thanks for the help guys.**
About the **LINQ** I manage to query the results using List, create a function that returns the met condition.

Code:

```
 private static bool CodeFiltered(string code)
        {
            return ((Convert.ToInt32(code.Substring(0,2)) >= 20));
 
        }


      var lstBudgetCodes = GetBudgetCodes();
            List<string> ResultCode =new List<string>(lstBudgetCodes.FindAll(CodeFiltered));
```

Comment: Please edit your question, instead of posting another question in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> `y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode.Substring(0,2) >'20'` but it says

> Too many characters in char literal

Indeed; you can only put one character inside `'` in C#. If you want to put more than one character, you need a string, which is delimited by `"`

> Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type string and char

`>` as a maths operation doesn't work with a string on one side and a char on the other. You can use it on two chars, or on two strings, but not on a mix

```
'a' > 'b'  //false
"a" > "b"  //false
"a" > "A"  //true - a is ASCII 97,  A is ASCII 65. 97 is greater than 65
```

I'd say you can simply use:

```
y.Whh_SubsidiaryCode >= "21Y"
```

if your code is always `number number Y`, but you should be aware that this is an alphameric comparison. It'll work fine for any other code that is also `number number Y`. Critically, a string of `100Y` is *not* greater than `21Y` because the first character, `1` is not greater than `2`

Unless you have other codes like `21X`, you can dump the `LIKE '%Y%'` / `Contains("y")` - that just slows things down

Comment: I cannot use this kind of solution since my formatting is not always "NumNumY" thats why I need to query first the column that contains "Y". Then filter out with ">=21"